# Getting undefined while using $(.className).val()

Tags: jquery, css, jsf

I am getting undefined when using $(.className).val() but $(.className) returns Object.Please suggest how can I get the value of text field in jquery.

Follwing is the code snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert($(".className").val());
});

<h:textField value="#{bean.firstName}" id="fiestName" class="className"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the text field is having a value assigned and with a class defined as 'className'?

Comment: can you alert `alert($(".className").length);` - looks like when the script is executed the text field is not yet added to the dom - may be dynamically created

Comment: I think you have another element with the same class name `className` . Keep it unique or use ID selector.

Comment: Its length is coming 1 on alert($(".className").length);

Comment: I have used unique class name, Just I cannot post it here  so changed it in post.

Comment: i may be wrong but value goes in elements that accept value, like input. Use a data attribute instead. --https://jsfiddle.net/b3t0moot/

Comment: Please, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The `<h:textField>` doesn't exist.

Comment: @BalusC while you are right about the `<h:textField>` why does it work [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e3mLffp2/1/) ??

Comment: @chsdk: because you're not dealing with JSF-produced HTML output, but with plain vanilla (X)HTML. It appears that you never really used or understood JSF/XHTML. I suggest you to carefully read our wiki pages on those subjects to get started on those technologies.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for your response, I got it now, but I think there's nothing wrong to ask such a question ?! After all we are all here to learn.

Comment: @chsdk: there's nothing wrong with a question as long as OP respects and understands http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Right now there are too many probable causes which cannot be eliminated based on the information provided so far. The context of the code snippet is completely missing and the code snippet itself is carelessly prepared (won't run at all when copypasted into a completely blank sandbox project with everything set to default). That's exactly why the OP has to provide a true MCVE. Else this question is simply a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **class** attribute with **styleClass** in your jsf defined tag attribute.

```
<h:textField value="#{bean.firstName}" id="fiestName" styleClass="className"/>
```

Comment: I am using styleClass="className" only, still same result.

Comment: seems to be a concern of uniqueness. The classname selector basically returns a collection which needs to be iterated using $(".className").each(function(key,value){}); Using a counter variable access the first element(it'll obviously be first if there is only one such DOM element on your page using this class.

Comment: Thanks  Devanshu Kashyap, Could you please explain how to select its first element??

Answer (score -1):

i think better using id as trigger to get value of textfield, because id is unique and class is not.

below my suggestion code (change selector inside alert):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert($("#fiestName").val());
});

<h:textField value="#{bean.firstName}" id="fiestName" class="className"/>
```

Comment: I am using unique class name.I can not use ID as its value is changed in html(Parent element added with :)

Answer (score -1):

do it with a function or write your jquery down the html code

```
<h:textField value="#{bean.firstName}" id="fiestName" class="className"/>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 alert($(".className").val());
  });
```